# How i can align my barcode on my pdf

Tags: java, pdf

I want to center my barcode because all my text is centered. How can I make this?

```
 para = new Paragraph(nom_ecole,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,45));
            para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            document.add(para);
           para = new Paragraph(nom_eleve1+" "+prenom_eleve1,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,45));
           para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           document.add(para);
           codebarre.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
           codebarre.setCode(id_doss1);
           document.add(codebarre.createImageWithBarcode(cb,BaseColor.BLACK,BaseColor.BLACK));
```

Comment: Which PDF library are you using?

Comment: I use the library Itext